# Outlook BCC prompt VBA doesn't automatically run

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, macros, prompt, bcc

I'm still pretty new to VBA (so sorry if this is a dumb question) though I am already coding small applications a few years for like buttons in excel or something. But this one has never ben clear to me; I want to implement this BCC prompt feature in an automatic loop for Outlook. When I run the macro, it works fine untill I restart Outlook. Why do I have to reactivate this macro every time over and over again when I start Outlook? I placed it in ThisOutlooksession, enabled all macro's (by the way; does this need to be enabled forever? seems unsafe to me) but no succes. If someone could help me out, that would be great! Thanks in advance.

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


End Sub

Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)


Dim prompt As String
prompt = "The BCC Field is empty!"



If Item.BCC = "" Then


    If msgbox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "BCC Field") = vbNo Then
    Cancel = True
    End If
 End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To automatically run `Initialize_handler`:

```
Private Sub Application_startup()
    Initialize_handler
End Sub
```

You can simplify with:

```
Private Sub Application_startup()
    Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End Sub
```

You can simplify by dropping all your code and using this instead:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim prompt As String
    prompt = "The BCC Field is empty!"

    If Item.BCC = "" Then
        If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "BCC Field") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application_Startup()` instead of `Initialize_handler()`.